# Derivation of Logistic regression

Tags: logistic, bayesian

I am trying to understand the derivation of logistic regression. Some books like the famous `Elements of Statistical Learning` just give you the formula without too much effort. Others try to explains it a little further.

The book `A first course in Machine Learning` for example does the following steps.
First of all it starts from applying Bayes to

$$P(\mathbf{w|t,X)}=\frac{P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}P(\mathbf{w)}}{P(\mathbf{t|X})}$$

where $\mathbf{w}$ is the vector of the model parameters, $\mathbf{X}$ is the input matrix and $\mathbf{t}$ the output vector.

1. My first question is: ***Why is it starting from this? Should not it start from $P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}?$***

Then it explains each term in the Bayes expression. Basically it says the numerator can be calculated while the denominator can not. The denominator is re-expressed as

$$P(\mathbf{t|X}) = \int P(\mathbf{t|w,X}) P(\mathbf{w}) d\mathbf{w}$$ and it says

> [...] we cannot analytically perform the integration required to compute the marginal likelihood. In other words we have a function $g(\mathbf{w,X,t}) = P(\mathbf{t|w,X}) P(\mathbf{w})$ which we know is proportional to the posterior, $P(\mathbf{w|t,X)}=Zg(\mathbf{w,X,t})$, but we do not know the constant of proportionality $Z^{-1}$.

2. ***Why it is not possible to perform the integration?*** Also assuming that when talking about proportionality it is rexpressing the posterior as:$P(\mathbf{w|t,X)}= \frac{P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}P(\mathbf{w)}}{\int P(\mathbf{t|w,X}) P(\mathbf{w}) d\mathbf{w}}$, which is not explained, it is not saying which type of proportionality is that (inversely/directly) is it? if so how?

Since we cannot compute these quantities it says we are left with 3 options (as I have understood to find $\mathbf{w}$):

> 1)Find the single value of $\mathbf{w}$ that corresponds to the highest value of posterior. As $g(\mathbf{w,X,t})$ is proportional to the posterior, a maximum of $g$ will correspond to a maximum of the posterior. $Z^{-1}$ is not a function of $w$.
>
> 2)Approximate $P(\mathbf{w|t,X})$ with some other density that we can compute analytically.
>
> 3) Sample directly from the posterior $P(\mathbf{w|t,X)}$ knowing only $g$

3. **It says the first is not very Bayesian: Why?** It gives the example Newton-Raphson method but other books use this method to fit the regression.
   Also if 
   $$P(\mathbf{w|t,X)}= \frac{P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}P(\mathbf{w)}}{\int P(\mathbf{t|w,X}) P(\mathbf{w}) d\mathbf{w}}$$ 
   is valid, **why a maximum in $g$ should correspond to a maximum in the posterior**? And **does logistic regression use a particular method or is it independent from that?**

Then it says

> Once we have the posterior density, we can predict the response class of new objects by taking an expectation with respect to  this density: $P(t_{new}=1|x_{new}|\mathbf{X,t}) = \mathbf{E}_{P(\mathbf{w|t,X)}}{\frac{1}{1+e^{-\mathbf{w^Tx_{new}}}}}$

4. Why is the expectation taken over $P(\mathbf{w|t,X)}$?
5. What is the first motivation of logistic regression? Does it start from the desire to keep the linearity hence using $w^Tx$ but forcing the model to output probabilities so passing the linear function to a sigmoid? Or is this just a consequence of the desire to use log-odds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. My first question is: ***Why is it starting from this? Should not it start from $P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}?$***

The statement is [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). It is used to derive the *posterior distribution* from *prior distribution* $P(\mathbf{w)}$ and *likelihood* $P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}$. I don't know what do you mean by "starting" from the likelihood, but in Bayesian setting, you need both elements: priors and likelihood.

> 2. ***Why it is not possible to perform the integration?***

It is not that the integral is "not possible to compute". There is no closed-form mathematical solution for this integral. In plain English, this means that there is no simple mathematical formula for it, where you could just plug-in the data and get the result. That is the reason, why we use methods like MCMC to *approximate* the integral.

> Also assuming that when talking about proportionality it is
>   rexpressing the posterior as: $P(\mathbf{w|t,X)}=
>  \frac{P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}P(\mathbf{w)}}{\int P(\mathbf{t|w,X})
>  P(\mathbf{w}) d\mathbf{w}}$, which is not explained, it is not saying
>   which type of proportionality is that (inversely/directly) is it? if
>   so how?

Hard to say what you mean, but my best guess is that what was meant in the handbook is

$$
P(\mathbf{w|t,X)} \propto P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}P(\mathbf{w)}
$$

so it is proportional if we drop the *normalizing constant* $Z^{-1}$ (using the notation mentioned by you later).

> 3. **It says the first is not very Bayesian: Why?** [...]

Because in Bayesian setting $\mathbf{w}$ is a random variable, so it has a distribution and you are interested in finding this distribution, rather then single "best" candidate.

> [...] **why a maximum in $g$ should correspond to a maximum in the
>   posterior**?

Because maximum of the posterior distribution is the maximum of the posterior distribution. As said earlier, $g$ is proportional to the posterior. In the optimization dividing $g$ by $Z$ would not make a difference in the result, so they are the same for this purpose. See also [Normalizing constant in Bayes theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12112/normalizing-constant-in-bayes-theorem), [Normalizing constant irrelevant in Bayes theorem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51493/normalizing-constant-irrelevant-in-bayes-theorem), and [Why Normalizing Factor is Required in Bayes Theorem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129666/why-normalizing-factor-is-required-in-bayes-theorem).

> And **does logistic regression use a particular method or
>   is it independent from that?**

The discussed model is a [Bayesian logistic regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163034/bayesian-logit-model-intuitive-explanation/163039#163039). There is also the "classical" logistic regression that does not use priors and Bayes theorem at all, if this is what you are asking.

> 4. Why is the expectation taken over $P(\mathbf{w|t,X)}$?

Because that is what we are interested in, aren't we? We want to estimate the distribution of the parameters $\mathbf{w}$ *given* the data we observed $\mathbf{t,X}$. The procedure is about estimating the parameters of the model.

> 5. What is the first motivation of logistic regression? Does it start from the desire to keep the linearity hence using $w^Tx$ but forcing
>      the model to output probabilities so passing the linear function to a
>      sigmoid?

Yes, that's it. You can think of logistic regression as of linear regression that [outputs probabilities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/227009/logistic-regression-how-to-call-the-output/228212#228212), where the target variable is binary (or is a [probability of binary event](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232979/logistic-regression-use-of-real-values-between-0-and-1as-opposed-to-two-clas/233003#233003)).

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. In 1) I mean that in other references they do not use $P(\mathbf{w|t,X)}$ for the derivation but $P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}$. Then in 2) and 3) what I meant is that it is not obvious (I do not know if incorrect) that $P(\mathbf{w|t,X)} \propto P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}P(\mathbf{w)}$ since at the denominator you have the integral of the numerator. In other words when  $P(\mathbf{t|w,X)}P(\mathbf{w)}$increases, so does its integral i.e., the denominator so the direct proportion is not guaranteed in my opinion.

Comment: Also when I asked if logistic regression use a particular method, I meant does it find a single value for $w$, does it estimate a distribution or does it use sampling ? Or LR is just the model that is independent from the way we find $w$? With the Newton-Raphson method, what kind of logistic regression are we deriving since it is not a very Bayesian method?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi (1) maybe other references do not discuss Bayesian model? (2) after you compute the integral, $Z$ is a single number (you integrate over all possible $\mathbf{w}$'s and $\mathbf{t,X}$ are constant), so it is dividing by constant; it does not influence optimization. As abput your second comment, maybe this helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163034/bayesian-logit-model-intuitive-explanation/163039#163039

Comment: Just another question: suppose a closed-form of the integral exist: then the procedure would be to define a loss function, perform its derivative, set to $0$ and verify it is a minimum just as in Linear regression?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi not exactly. If there was closed form solution, then the posterior *distribution* would be directly available. Given it, you could easy estimate model of the distribution (maximum), or expected value etc. It would be equivalent to regular logistic regression with flat prior $p(\mathbf{w}) \propto 1$.

Comment: +1 the sheer courage it takes to answer so many questions in the same post rather than flagging as too broad is worth mentioning I think

Comment: @patrickCoulombe there many question true, but they are all linked to the single atomic problem of logistic regression derivation, so I don't see why it should be flagged

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe in some cases I'd mark it as too broad, in other answer, or leave for others to answer. Neither extreme: always closing, or always answering, is the good solution. In here, I considered it as a single question with clear follow-ups. If someone asked multiple questions on very different subjects, or very specific ones, I'd rather close.